# How to choose inaugural (very first) number that would be a mask for a number

Tags: c, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators

As my question, how to choose or determine inaugural / very first number that would be a mask for a number?

I learn manipulating (set, clear, etc) bit in ansi C. Many tutorials doesn't explain how to choose / determine the mask. For example:

```c
// 1st tutorial
unsigned char foo = 0;
foo = foo | 0b0000000000000001; // how to determine this number we need number 1 (0b0000000000000001) as the mask?

// 2nd tutorial
#define Bitset(var,bitno) ((var) |=1UL<<(bitno)) // why choose 1UL ??
```

// 3rd tutorial
// From http://teaching.idallen.com/cst8214/08w/notes/bit_operations.txt

```
    10101010 = AAh
AND 00001111 = 0Fh  <-- this is the 4-bit mask
```

at 3rd tutorial how they determine to choose 00001111 as a mask for 10101010 ?

Comment: What do you mean with " inaugural / very first number"?

Comment: @PaulOgilvie, i don't know how to express it in english. I mean how to choose a mask ? if i want to bit-masking a number. as i wrote in 2nd tutorial, why they choose 1UL ? is it always 1UL. i know 1UL is 1 integer unsigned long. thank you..

Comment: `1UL` is simply the constant `1` expresses as an `unsigned long`. As far as determining the mask, a mask is just the hexidecimal number that represents the binary string necessary to mask the number and combination of bits you are interested in.  For example the mask for the first `14`-bits of any number (i.e. `11111111111111`) is simply `3FFF`. No magic, it's just what the binary value  `11111111111111` is in `hex`. (because it is a hell of a lot easier to write `3FFF`)

Answer (score 1):

They don't "determine" the number, they just give examples of bitwise AND and OR operators. They take two numbers (represented by bits) and apply a bitwise operation to it, showing you the result of the operation.

The example `foo = foo | 0b0000000000000001;` could just be written as `foo = foo | 1;` or even as `foo |= 1;`

The maco `#define Bitset(var,bitno) ((var) |=1UL<<(bitno))` sets bit `bitno` to one (the first bit is bit zero). It takes the number `1` of the largest integer type (long - L), unsigned (U), so the highest bit will not be seen as the sign, and shift that `bitno` positions (bits) to the left. Because they take the largest integer type, it will work on any (smaller or the same size) integer type and where the macro is used, the compiler will scale the result back to a smaller type if needed.

For example:

```
int i= 0x2220;
i= Bitset(i,3);
```

`i` has now become 0x2228.